# RxJava with SQlite and ContentProvider operations

Tags: android, sqlite, rx-java

I'm studying RxJava and to do this I'm playing with SQLite, writing an helper class `SQLiteUtils` in order to help handling asynchronous ContentResolver queries easier. 
For example this is the `queryInBackground` method:

```
static
public <T> Observable<T> queryInBackground(
        final ContentResolver cr,
        final Uri uri,
        final String[] projection,
        final String selection,
        final String[] selectionArgs,
        final String sortOrder,
        final CursorHandler<T> ch) {
    return  Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<T>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super T> observer) {
            if (!observer.isUnsubscribed()) {
                Cursor cursor = null;
                try {
                    cursor = cr.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                            observer.onNext(ch.handle(cursor));
                        }
                    }
                    observer.onCompleted();
                } catch (Exception err) {
                    observer.onError(err);

                } finally {
                    if (cursor != null) cursor.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());
}
```

where `CursorHandler` is an interface:

```
/**
 * Implementations of this interface convert Cursor into other objects.
 *
 * @param <T> the target type the input Cursor will be converted to.
 */
public interface CursorHandler<T> {
    T handle(Cursor cu) throws SQLException;
}
```

I've read the docs about [Schedulers](http://reactivex.io/documentation/scheduler.html#collapseRxJava), but I'm not quite sure if `Schedulers.computation()` was the right choice.

And if I'd like to implements something similiar for basic `HttpUrlConnection` operations, wich Scheduler I should pick? `Schedulers.newThread()` or `Schedulers.io()`, I'd stick with `Schedulers.io()` ...but not sure.

Thanks in advance.

All the best,
luca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276164/rxjava-schedulers-use-cases) you should use `Schedulers.io()`. Relevant quote:

> io() is backed by an unbounded thread-pool and is the sort of thing
>   you'd use for non-computationally intensive tasks, that is stuff that
>   doesn't put much load on the CPU. So yep interaction with the file
>   system, interaction with databases or services on a different host are
>   good examples.

Comment: @LucaSepe my pleasure. Also you might wanna check out SQLBrite https://github.com/square/sqlbrite