# How to invoke a method for each element in a collection parallely using RxJava

Tags: rx-java

I have below two methods and need to invoke findDetails(name) method parallely for all names in the list. How can achieve this using RxJava?
 Basically I want to invoke findDetails method for each element in teh collection in diffrent threads.

```
public List<Bean> findStudentDetails(List<String> names){

        names.forEach(s->{
            findDetails(s);
         });

}


private Bean findDetails(String name){
           //some io operation
         }
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more. what do you mean by parallel here?

Comment: @Akbar I have rephrase my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your methods to return `Observable`, then `flatMap` your `Observables` with applied `subscribeOn` operator:

```
private Observable<Bean> findDetails(String name) {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> { //or any other creation method
        //some io operation
    }
}

public Observable<List<Bean>> findStudentDetails(List<String> names) {
    return Observable.from(names)
        .flatMap(s -> findDetails(s).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .toList()
}
```

**Note**: computation `Scheduler` limits threads count to the number of available CPU cores for better performance on intense operations. For more information check this great answer about `Schedulers` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31282775/7045114

Also check this article about parallelization - http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.ru/2015/11/rxjava-achieving-parallelization.html