# Can I change the behaviour of Schedulers.io() in RxJava?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276164/rxjava-schedulers-use-cases), `Schedulers.io()` will create an unbounded number of threads. In my application, this is an issue because I have hundreds of asynchonous tasks to complete.

The recommendation in the comments is to use `Scheduler.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n))`, which is reasonable, but the usage pattern is different to `Schedulers.io()`:

- With `Schedulers.io()`, I can re-use the same thread-pool through-out my application, and Rx will properly call `shutdown` for me.
- With `Scheduler.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n))`, I have to make the `Scheduler` available across my application and remember to call `shutdown`.

Questions:

- Can I just tweak the behaviour of `Schedulers.io()` to use a bounded thread-pool?
- What is the recommended way to thread a `Scheduler` through-out an Rx application, and ensure that it is `shutdown` correctly?

Comment: Maybe [`Schedulers.computation()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/schedulers/Schedulers.html#computation()) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

For RxJava, you can use `RxJavaHooks.onIOScheduler` to return your `Scheduler` as `Schedulers.io`. But you can't avoid `IOScheduler` be created.

For RxJava2, you can use `RxJavaPlugins.setInitIoSchedulerHandler` to init the `IOScheduler` by your `Scheduler` directly.

Comment: Could you give an example of `setInitIoSchedulerHandler`? The API is not what I expected.

Comment: @sdgfsdh Use `RxJavaPlugins.setInitIoSchedulerHandler(c -> mySchedler);` to set `myScheduler` as `IOScheduler` before `Schedulers`'s initialization.

Comment: What is `c`? Do I need to dispose of `myScheduler` later in my code?

Comment: @sdgfsdh If you see the code of `setInitIoSchedulerHandler`, you will not ask 'what is c'. You need to dispose your `myScheduler` later. If you want it dispose automatically, I have a solution on [link](https://github.com/XDean/Java-EX/blob/master/src/main/java/xdean/jex/extra/rx/RxUtil.java). `Executor` will dispose itself when the `Scheduler` be recycled.