# RxJava: How to make observable to create on different thread than main thread

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I want observable code to run on different thread than main thread. How can I do this, I'm doing like this:

```
Observable operationObservable = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter e) throws Exception {
            e.onNext(longRunningOperation());
            e.onComplete();
        }
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // subscribeOn the I/O thread
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Comment: Well, try using a different thread in `observeOn`?

Comment: You can instruct an `Observable` to send its notifications to observers on a particular Scheduler by means of the `ObserveOn` operator. by that you can use your `Scheduler` or class which implements `Scheduler` to observe

Comment: Your example does exactly that. `subscribeOn` will make sure the body of the `ObservableOnSubscribe.subscribe` is executing in one of the IO threads of the IO Scheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a new thread to run something on you can just use `subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())`.

Another alternative would be to create your own scheduler and executors which is really not necessary for most cases.

Further reading:
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276164/rxjava-schedulers-use-cases?rq=1)
[link2](https://praveer09.github.io/technology/2016/02/29/rxjava-part-3-multithreading/)
[link3](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html)