# Rxjava2 Schedulers.io() vs Schedulers.computation() with large concurrent request

Tags: rx-java2

I am using Rxjava2 with spring boot.

I have 500 concurrent request on server.

Each request spawns 10 threads which calls other services(so IO work)

So in this case, should I use `Schedulers.io()` or `Schedulers.compuatation()`.

Basically my confusion is ideally `io()` should be used as this is IO work, 
but this could create large number of threads?

Also can i specify the pool size of computation threads?
Also can i specify the pool size of io threads?

Comment: this doesn't answer your specific question, but if you're looking for more control over the number of threads created, you can use `Schedulers.from(Executor)` with an executor instance configured with a custom thread management policy.

Answer (score 5):

> should I use Schedulers.io() or Schedulers.compuatation().

You want to calls other services, it's I/O work, so you **should not** use `computation()`. Because it's best to leave `computation()` for **CPU intensive work only** otherwise you won't get good CPU utilization.

> can i specify the pool size of computation threads?

No, `computation()` is backed by a bounded thread-pool with size equal to **the number of available processors**. So if you want to spawns 10 threads, you **cannot** do it.

> can i specify the pool size of io threads

If you need to limit the maximum number of simultaneous network calls, use: `Scheduler.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))`

It's unnecessary for your use-case, because you only do 10 task at a same time. But it's a good practice, because `io()` is unbounded and if you need to schedule hundreds tasks in parallel then each of them will have their own thread and causes context switching overhead.

For more information, see: [rxJava Schedulers Use Cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31282775/5282585)
.

Comment: can you tell me more about what is  CPU intensive work? everywhere written the same. I am confused, does meaning network operations or read-write work?

Comment: No one explains what can be termed as CPU intensive work, someone will say when processing huge data but no one will answer huge data means how much and in what conditions?

Comment: CPU intensive is something that takes a long time to operate (manipulate bitmap,...).

Comment: I'm not so expert in RxJava, but I think there actually IS a way to modify the pool size of Scheduler.computation ([see Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/rxjava-schedulers#computation)): _If for some reason, we need a different number of threads than the default, we can always use the_ `rx.scheduler.max-computation-threads` _system property_