# Subscribe on Observable Does Nothing

Tags: java, observable, rx-java2

I am trying to understand how Observables are executed but can't seem to get this simple code to work.

```
public class RxJavaExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable<String> hello = Observable.fromCallable(() -> 
            getHello()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());

        hello.subscribe();

        System.out.println("End of main!");
    }

    public static String getHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello called in " + 
            Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Shouldn't `hello.subscribe()` execute `getHello()`?

Comment: isnt `getHello()` executed ?

Comment: @SantanuSur Nope, its never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sfiss is right, this works just as you would expect:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class RxJavaExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Observable<String> hello = Observable.fromCallable(() -> getHello())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(exec));

    hello.subscribe();

    System.out.println("End of main!");

    exec.shutdown();
    exec.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  public static String getHello() {
    System.out.println("Hello called in " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return "Hello";
  }
}
```

With the following output:

```
End of main!
Hello called in pool-1-thread-1
```

Comment: Accepting this over @sfiss as this answer is more complete.

Comment: This doesnt cover observables just threading, and as such isnt actually answering the title question. There appears to be confusion with Threads and observables

Comment: @TheresaForster while you are technically correct, the problem OP was experiencing was due to the asynchronous nature of the subscriber.

Comment: Looks like we can also do a blocking subscribe -- `subscribe(Observable::blockingSubscribe)`

Answer (score 2):

It is because your main thread finishes, before the background thread gets to `getHello`. Try to add a `Thread.sleep(5000)` in your `main` method before exiting.

Alternatively, wait until the `onCompleted` of your subscription is called.

EDIT: The reason why the program terminates is because RxJava spawns [daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-a-daemon-thread-in-java) threads. On the search for a good source, I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791902/rxjava-subscribeonschedulers-newthread-questions) question, which probably answers it as well.

Comment: I don't think a Java program will exit until all threads complete. Moreover I did put a breakpoint in the `getHello()` method, it was never called.

Comment: Why would you not try it out, instead of assuming that you are correct and know how it works? Please have a look at my edits. Maybe also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-a-daemon-thread-in-java

Comment: Java does happily exit without waiting for threads to finish, that's why we have ExecutorService.awaitTermination.

Comment: LeffeBrune, I didn't initially know that RxJava created daemon threads till @sfiss pointed it out. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score -1):

It may be you are getting confused between Threads and Observables,

The way I have used Observables in the past is for a timer on a Minecraft plugin, I have an event that is triggered every minute.

```
public class TimerHandler extends Observable implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.setChanged();
        this.notifyObservers();
    }
}
```

So this triggers every minute, and then to add events to the timer queue you just subscribe to the observable meaning that the subscribed calls are triggered every minute.

```
public class PlotTimer implements Observer {

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        ......
```

to subscribe i call the following

```
getServer().getScheduler().scheduleAsyncRepeatingTask(this,timerHandler,1200,1200);
timerHandler.addObserver(new PayDayTimer());
timerHandler.addObserver(new ProfileTimer());
timerHandler.addObserver(new PlotTimer());
```

Comment: The question is not taking about `java.util.Observable` but RxJava. Both mine and the accepted answer detail how RxJava uses daemon threads and how to prevent the early shutdown.

Comment: @Theresa AFAIK the recommended way is to use tags for specifying the tech instead of mentioning in the title.